# Foreign key constraint despite having referenced records in the referenced table in web2py when using SQLFORM for users having id > 3

Tags: web2py

I am getting "foreign key constraint failed" error. I have the records in the referenced tables, though. This happens only for the logged in user.It works fine for users with id <= 3 but not for others.

Here is the related db.py code:

```
    db.define_table('Roles',    
            Field('person', db.auth_user),    
            Field('role'))    
    db.define_table('Doctors',
            Field('doctor', db.auth_user, required = True),    
            Field('age', 'integer', required = True),    
            Field('qualification'),    
            Field('specialization'),    
            format = '%(doctor)s'    
            )    

    db.define_table('Patients',    
            Field('patient', db.auth_user, required = True),    
            Field('age', 'integer', required = True),    
            Field('doctor', db.Doctors, required = True),     
            Field('temperature', 'double'),     
            Field('blood_pressure', 'double'),     
            Field('haemoglobin', 'double'),     
            Field('contact_name'),     
            Field('contact_phone', 'bigint'),     
            format = '%(patient)s'     
           )     

    db.define_table('Assignments',     
            Field('doctor', 'reference Doctors', unique = False),     
            Field('patient', 'reference Patients', unique = False))
```

Here is the related default.py code:

```
def registerRole():    
role = int(request.args[0])    
form = FORM()    
if role == 1:    
    form = SQLFORM(db.Doctors).process()    
elif role == 2:    
    form = SQLFORM(db.Patients).process()    
if form.accepted:    
    response.flash = 'form accepted'    
    if role == 1:    
        db.Roles.insert(person = auth.user.id, role = 'doctor')
            auth.add_membership(auth.id_group('doctor'),auth.user.id)
        elif role == 2:
            i = 1
           db.Assignments.insert(doctor = int(form.vars.doctor), patient = auth.user.id)    
         db.Roles.insert(person = auth.user.id, role = 'patient')    
         auth.add_membership(auth.id_group('patient'),auth.user.id)    
     redirect(URL('index'))    
else:    
    response.flash = form.errors    
return dict(form = form, role = role)
```

Please help me out in this issue. I have been stuck at it for quite sometime now. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.Assignments.insert(doctor = int(form.vars.doctor), patient = auth.user.id)
```

Above you are setting the value of `patient` to `auth.user.id`, which is an `id` in the `auth_user` table. However, the `patient` field of `Assignments` must instead be an `id` from the `Patients` table, as it is of type `reference Patients`. Instead, you probably want the `id` of the record that was just inserted in `Patients` by the form, which is in `form.vars.id`:

```
db.Assignments.insert(doctor = int(form.vars.doctor), patient = form.vars.id)
```

Also, consider that `auth.user.id` is always the `id` of the currently logged in user. It is not clear that your other uses of `auth.user.id` are appropriate (i.e., with `db.Roles.insert` and `auth.add_membership`), as the user selected as the doctor or patient in the form is not necessarily going to be the logged in user.